# What is the best way to persist data in android?

Tags: android

In my android application, i want to persist some information when system kills or force stop my activity or process. Which is the best among Bundle and sqlite database.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to persist some information when system kills or force stop my activity or process.

You can't. When the system force stops your app, it is simply killed. No callbacks are invoked.

You should persist data whenever your Activity's onPause() method is called.

For simple int, String etc. values, you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). For more organized or larger datasets, you should use an [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Comment: Adding to this, what @Raghav Sood means is ofcourse that you can't JUST do it whenever the system kills your activity. You should just save important data as soon as possible before something like that happens.

Comment: tried persisting serialized objects to a file using threads and handlers. giving myself serious headaches.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the data you want to maintain. For just a few configuration information, or single variables, just use the Bundle. SQlite is more complex but allows searches and data editing that is science-fi with the Bundle.
Generally speaking, unless needed, use the Bundle.
Obviously it's implicit that the use of Bundle is not automatic and you have to write the data into it before the application is killed, in the onDestroy() or in the onPause(). It is intended right for that, to preserve dynamic data from one run to another run of the same activity.
In the easiest scenario, for just few strings or ints, if you want to keep data persistently, you should choose a third option, the SharedPreferences.